# How to use Function return

Tags: vb.net, function

I'm wondering if this is the right way to do this.
I have this sample code that should represent a user action, and a calculation done in a function, this function should then return the value to my sub?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Test_function(i)
    MsgBox(i)
End Sub

Private Function Test_function(ByVal i As Integer)
    i = i + 1
    Return (i)
End Function
```

When i run this piece of code I get:

i = 1 in sub

i = 2 in function

i = 1 in sub?

How do you get the i = 2 into my sub? Or is this not the correct way of using this?

Comment: `Dim myVar = Test_function(i)`  MyVar will hold the value returned - your code has nothing to capture/hold/store the return

Comment: You can also write "i = Test_function(i)"

Comment: Oh I see, got it going now!!  thanks for the comments!

Comment: @JefE It's just like functions in math. `y = f(x)` --> `Dim y As Integer = Test_function(i)`.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and turn on Option Strict either by adding `Option Strict On` at the top of the code file or by setting it in the Project's properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're asking is why does `i` not get changed by the call to Test_function.

Let's break down your code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 1 'creating a variable named i, value 1.
    Test_function(i) 'passing the value of the variable i to test function, but not doing anything with what the function returns.
    MsgBox(i) 'calling messagebox with the value i.
End Sub

Private Function Test_function(ByVal i As Integer) 'creating a new variable also named i with the value being passed in.
    i = i + 1 'incrementing the value of the i variable by 1.
    Return (i) 'returning i 
End Function
```

So there are a few concepts that you're misunderstanding as far as I can tell- what `ByVal` means, perhaps the concept of variable scoping, as well as what `Return` does.

The obvious answer is that you're not using the value returned by `Test_function`. If you had `i = test_Function(i)`, then `i` would be incremented by the call to `Test_function`

Another approach would be to pass `i` ByRef instead of ByVal- if you did that, the `i` in the scope of your `Test_function` method would be the same as the `i` in the scope of your `Button1_Click` method. But because you are passing it `ByVal`, the `i` variables are actually two completely different variables.

Comment: So, correct me if i'm wrong, use ByRef if you want to edit a variable value and return it & use ByVal to use a value but don't return it? Is this the best way to use this?

Comment: No, ByRef vs ByVal just control if you're passing a value or sharing the reference. If you share the reference, both methods will be looking at the same memory location, and modifications in the called method will be reflected in the calling method regardless of if the value is returned. If you pass the value, modifications within the called method do not reflect at the calling method. However, this can mean different things if what you're passing is a class vs a primitive such as an integer. Read This-> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eek064h4.aspx

Comment: Note that by default in VB, everything is ByVal, so `Test_Function(ByVal i As Integer)` is the same as `TestFunction(i As Integer)`

Comment: Thanks for the response! This helps alot.

Is there also a way to return multiple values / references?
Return(i, y)

Comment: No, you can pass values `ByRef`, use `out` parameters, or return a custom class or expandoobject, but there are no multiple returns in vb as there are in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to wonder, it's only a simple misunderstanding. you are printing the actual value of `i` if you Call like this:

```
MsgBox(Test_function(i))
```

Then both will be the same;
or you can check this in following way:

```
Dim tempVal = Test_function(i)'<-- will give 2
MsgBox(i)'<--- will give 1
```

this is because you are passing the value of `i` not i as reference, if you pass it as reference then also both will be the same.
So if you change the function signature as follows:

```
Private Function Test_function(ByRef i As Integer)
    i = i + 1
    Return (i)
End Function
```

same function call will give you both values as `2`

```
 Dim tempVal = Test_function(i)'<-- will give 2
 MsgBox(i)'<--- will give 2
```

[Reference ByVal and ByRef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx)